# Allow traffic on Ubuntu Server 19.10

Tags: networking, server, python, raspberrypi

I've installed Ubuntu Server 19.10 on my Raspberry Pi 3B, but I've an issue with a Python script.

This script starts an http server on a specific port and I can launch a comand from outside network. I've installed it before on my Windows pc and it works.

What I did:
- my Windows pc ip: 192.168.0.10
- my Ubuntu server ip: 192.168.0.20
- port forwarding: external port 1010 - to 192.168.0.10:1010
- port forwarding: external port 2020 - to 192.168.0.20:2020
- configured dynamic dns with no-ip: example.ddns.it
(these are example data)

Then, I've tested the url with this site: https://reqbin.com/ with:
- example.ddns.it:1010/command - it works (Windows)
- example.ddns.it:2020/command - `The request timed out.` (Ubuntu Server)
- example.ddns.it:3030/command - `Connection error occurred.` (nothing, it's correct, it's only a test)

I've already tried with `sudo ufw disable` and starting the Python script with `sudo python3 m_server.py`. Nothing.

I think that it's related to Ubuntu Server, because on the Windows pc it works without issues or a specific configuration.

Answer (score 1):

*"This script starts an http server on a specific port and I can launch a comand from outside network."*

Are these two things related?
Can you elaborate?

The IP's you shared are all private.
How is this traffic going to get to your server from the outside world (if that is even what you want).
You might consider that firewalls are more than just traffic blockers anymore.
I use iptables to control traffic direction on my linux router.
Squid caches much of my static traffic making my connection seem faster than it really is but iptables listens for traffic on a particular nic and port and forwards it on as needed.
Disabling ufw was a good test but you might see if ufw can do port forwarding which is what it sounds like you need.
On your server, run the relevant "ip" command to see if there is a service listening on port 2020.
For example, "ip addr" will display your ip addresses and nic info.
There is another "ip" command that will display ports that are being listened to and which of your IP addresses is doing the listening.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't edit the aswer... I've solved, the system had gotten the wrong gateway from another router in my net.